# Convert MSSQL table to MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, create-table

How to convert the below table into MySQL?

```
CREATE TABLE cmps(
`Id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`Estck` int NOT NULL,
`Qstck` int NOT NULL,
`Sstck` int NOT NULL,
`Rstck` int NOT NULL,
`Bstck` int NOT NULL,
`Shstck` int NOT NULL,
`Avlstck`  AS ([Sstck]-(([Rstck]+[Bstck]);+`Shstck`)),
 CONSTRAINT `PK_cmps` PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
`Id` ASC
)
```

I have an issue with the below line.

```
   `Avlstck`  AS ([Sstck]-(([Rstck]+[Bstck]);+`Shstck`)),
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL version `5.7.6` or later?

Comment: Also it would be more helpful to see the original SQL Server query.

Comment: OP or anyone, out of learners curiosity can anyone explain what does `([Sstck]-(([Rstck]+[Bstck]);+`Shstck`))` mean ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I am using MySQL 6.3.9 version.

Comment: @PrabhatG It is gibberish AFAIK...hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at [Mysql documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) for computed columns, looks like you need to mention datatype for `Avlstck`. Also you need to remove those square brackets and semicolon

```
`Avlstck` int  AS (`Sstck`-((`Rstck`+`Bstck`) +`Shstck`))
```